# Laravel eloquent possible bug?

Tags: laravel, pdo, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I want to join two tables and filter on a field in the joined table. I don't think the actual tables matter in this question, but it's a table with dates joined with a table with the event info, so there are more dates possible for 1 event.
I made this eloquent line:

```
Event_date::whereRaw('startdate >= curdate() OR enddate >= curdate()')->whereHas('Event', function($q){$q->where("approved",true );})->orderBy('startdate', 'asc')->orderBy('enddate', 'asc')->toSql());
```

the filter doesn't work though. So thats why i added the ->toSql() to the line.
I get the following back:

```
select * from `event_dates` where startdate >= curdate() OR enddate >= curdate() and exists (select * from `events` where `event_dates`.`event_id` = `events`.`id` and `approved` = ?) order by `startdate` asc, `enddate` asc
```

You see that the 'where("approved",true )' results in 'where ..... and and `approved` = ?)'  Where does the questionmark come from??? I tried diferent things, like '1', 1, 'True', True, true, 'true'...everything comes back as a questionmark.

Any suggestions??

Thanks!

Erwin

Comment: PDO works like that! It sends '?' placeholders, and an array of corresponding values. It is to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. Laravel uses prepared statements. To get parameters that are put into placeholders, you can use

```
$query->getBindings();
```

so for example in your case you can use:

```
$query = Event_date::whereRaw('startdate >= curdate() OR enddate >= curdate()')->whereHas('Event', function($q){$q->where("approved",true );})->orderBy('startdate', 'asc')->orderBy('enddate', 'asc'));
```

and now

```
echo $query->toSql();
var_dump($query->getBindings());
```

to get both query with placeholders and values that will be put in place of placeholders.